# CRUD operation for nested model in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new in rails 3, and following the guide in ruby site I build the first blog application.

However in the app,the model "Comment" do not have edit/update/delete operation.

Then I tried to add it,but I fails.

Instead of just generate model for model "Comment",I create the scaffold for model "Comment" using:

```
rails generate scaffold Comment commenter:string body:text post:references
```

And in the post.show page,I modify it like this:

```
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= comment.commenter %></td>
    <td><%= comment.body %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_comment_path(comment) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', comment, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

They are listed,but when I click the 'edit' or 'delete' link,it will try to  jump to:

```
http://localhost:3000/comments/1
```

And Then I will get the error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/comments/3/edit" or

No route matches [DELETE] "/comments/3"
```

I have no idea now.

Is there any demo out of box I can learn?

---

UPdate:

In the routes.rb:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

Note:the following is confided manually by myself.

config generated by rails is :

```
resources :posts
resources :comments
```

Why I modify it is that in the comment build form,the post url should be "/posts/1/comments" for create new Comment,otherwise the post url will be "/comments" which will not associate the post and the comment.

Comment: how does your routes.rb look like?

Comment: @hguser: see the update in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you configure your `routes`? Your `config/routes.rb` should contain

```
resources :comments
```

you can also run `rake routes` to see what are the available url for your application based on your resource configuration.

**Edit:**

For a *demo* you can try [this video on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fgCM-CR0EXs&feature=player_detailpage#t=301s). However, you can find lots of videos in web regarding this.

**Edit:**

So seems you need your comment resource in two ways. Both as a nested resource of posts and top level resource as well. So you can have two things together then

```
resources :posts do
   resources :comments
end
resources :comments
```

Comment: I should not have deleted my previous comment, seems your answer is a mere copy/paste of it

Comment: @hguser is generating the scaffold, so it auto update the routes file.

Comment: ya thats the ideal case. But route errors completely related with route configuration. So he must have some problem with his route

Comment: @hguser: did it really work for you? if yes pls accept the answer.

Comment: @SamironPaul:In fact I just want the comments as top level resource.

Comment: @hguser: hmm... then would you please explain this from your post? `...in the comment build form,the post url should be "/posts/1/comments...`. This says that `comment` is a nested resource of `post`

Comment: @SamironPaul:I am so sorry,I comment wrong. IN fact,I want the comments just as nested resource.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've nested resources, you should use:

```
edit_post_comment_path(@post, comment)
```

to be even clearer:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_comment_path(@post, comment) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post_comment_path(@post, comment), confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td>
```